# I don't know how to find strumming patterns

Tags: guitar, strumming

Basically, I want to play this song "Love Was My Alibi" by Kris Fogelmark but I can't find the strumming pattern. I have been taking guitar classes for 6 years but dropped out but I still want to play guitar but I need help with strumming patterns. Can someone help me find the strumming pattern and teach me how to?

Comment: Click on the link to the duplicate question and I believe you will find some excellent advice.